# Can ping default gateway, but no internet

Tags: routing, cisco-asa

I have a Cisco ASA 5506-X with following configuration:

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address *.*.114.179 255.255.255.240 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.247.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 nameif backup
 security-level 1
 ip address *.*.*.97 255.255.255.252 
!

access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip 10.247.1.0 255.255.255.0 any log 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip any 10.247.1.0 255.255.255.0 

object network inside_lan
 nat (any,outside) dynamic interface

route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 *.*.114.177 128
```

With this configuration I can reach (ping) default gateway (*.*.114.177) from inside network (10.247.1.0/24) - , and that's all, no Internet connection can be established. Is anything wrong with this configuration, or configuration is OK and I should look elsewhere?

Comment: We need to see the rest of the ASA configuration to say for sure.

Comment: It sounds like you're in a walled garden. Do you know for certain that your ISP isn't routing you into a walled garden?

Comment: Have you performed a traceroute to see how far your connection gets?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing:

```
object network inside_lan
    Subnet 10.247.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

On an unrelated note, you probably will want to remove the `access-list outside_access_in`

Comment: Allows https ,http on outside to inside access -list for return traffic . For internet access from LAN

Comment: @SagarUragonda the ASA is a stateful firewall, return traffic is automatically permitted for existing connections in the connection table.